# Embedded Jetty and Spring MVC not mapping index.jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty

I am relatively new to Spring MVC, and have a working knowledge of Embedded Jetty. We have an existing Spring MVC webapp which I can compile into a war and drop into Tomcat, and it works fine. However I now want to run it in Embedded Jetty instead of having to drop it into Tomcat.

I have followed this tutorial which I found helpful (with a few small changes):

http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/using-embedded-jetty-spring-mvc/

And everything seems to be 'almost' ok, except the mappings for my jsps don't seem to work.

Here is my main class:

```
public class EmbeddedJetty {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;
    private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/";
    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml";
    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/*";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new EmbeddedJetty().startJetty(getPortFromArgs(args));
    }

    private static int getPortFromArgs(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
            }
        }
        return DEFAULT_PORT;
    }

    private void startJetty(int port) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(port);
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = getServletContextHandler(context);
        server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);

        server.start();
        server.join();

        ResourceHandlerRegistry rhr = new ResourceHandlerRegistry(context, servletContextHandler.getServletContext());
        rhr.addResourceHandler("images/**").addResourceLocations("images/");
        rhr.addResourceHandler("jsp/**").addResourceLocations("jsp/");
        rhr.addResourceHandler("css/**").addResourceLocations("css/");
    }

    private static ServletContextHandler getServletContextHandler(WebApplicationContext context) throws IOException {
        ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
        contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
        contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
        ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet);
        contextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, MAPPING_URL);
        contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
        return contextHandler;
    }

    private static WebApplicationContext getContext() {
        XmlWebApplicationContext context = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        return context;
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <!-- Welcome file -->
    <display-name>USER Administration</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- This is the servlet that will route to the correct Controller based on annotations -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!--Map non-resource URLs to the DispatcherServlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Allow access to the resources -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my spring-servlet.xml (relevant parts - I think):

```
    <!-- This is the base package(s) for where spring should scan for @Component, @Service, @Controller, etc -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.user.admin" />

     <!-- A resolver for the returned ModelAndView objects and other strings, this tells it to append .jsp and look in the /WEB-INF/jsp/ for it -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- loads in property files for use in this config -->
   <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:Frameworks/hibernate.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:Frameworks/activemq.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 3 session factory used for session management -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:${hibernate.config.location}" />
    </bean>
```

I then build it with the maven shade plugin, and run it with the following command:

```
java -classpath c:\dev\customclasspath;target\user-admin.jar com.admin.main.EmbeddedJetty
```

It starts up, and all looks fine in the logs, and I see lots of lines where it is loading my Java classes onto URLs:

```
Mapped URL path [/modifyUser] onto handler 'menuController
Mapped URL path [/modifyUser.*] onto handler 'menuControll
Mapped URL path [/modifyUser/] onto handler 'menuControlle
Mapped URL path [/addUser] onto handler 'menuController'
Mapped URL path [/addUser.*] onto handler 'menuController'
Mapped URL path [/addUser/] onto handler 'menuController'
```

But when I try to load up my app at "localhost:8080", I get a 'Not Found -- Powered by Jetty' page, and in the logs I see the following message:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-6910fe28'
```

What am I doing wrong? In my jar file, I can see the file /webapp/index.jsp, so I thought it might be that, but if I do "localhost:8080/webapp/" that doesn't work either. I have no idea what to change now, any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT1**

I believe the issue is because it is not actually loading my web.xml file (where I define the servlet-mappings) because I am creating the Jetty Context as the spring context, and not a 'WebAppContext'. However, I need the spring-servlet.xml file because it contains all my Controllers. How do I load both?

Answer (score 0):

The welcome file is used only when there is no servlet mapping for a URI. In your case there is one:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This handles **anything** except for .png/.js/.css.

Comment: Does this mean that the main page for my webapp can not be index.jsp anymore, and has to be a spring controller? The index.jsp approach works fine when deployed as a war file into an existing Tomcat instance

Comment: @Matt You can also add this to your `spring-servlet.xml`: `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>`. The jsp has to be in the `jsp` folder then.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the suggested change, but still when I access "localhost:8080/" in the logs I see "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jsp/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet" :(

Comment: @Matt Does your embedded Jetty have JSP support enabled by default or at all? A JSP URL should be picked up by a JSP servlet. BTW: Have you considered using Spring Boot instead of this approach?

Comment: In terms of whether it has JSP support, I actually have no idea - I just kinda assumed it did! (Jetty 8.1.15). How do I check? I have not come across Spring Boot before, I'll have a read up on that, thanks.